# Official documentation for Gstreamer Plugin workflow

Tags: gstreamer

I'm writing High Level Design for the Gstreamer **source plugin** I wrote few months ago. But I met trouble when I try to express the workflow of gstreamer src plugin. I know that some interfaces(like set_caps,negotiate, etc.) are inherited from GstBaseSrc or GstElement, but what's the standard call sequence of these interfaces? Is there any **official documentation** to make my HLD more convincible? I'll be obliged if you could share one with me.  :)

Comment: BYW, I checked Plugin Writer's Guide from freedesktop.com, but it didn't provide enough information that I need.

Comment: what about [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseSrc.html).. check the description - there is lot of text :P